# why mixin is selected over prototypical inheritance

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the chapter about `observers` [here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript) and there is the following code which implements interface for `Subject` entity:

```
function Subject(){...}
Subject.prototype.addObserver = function( observer ){...};
Subject.prototype.removeObserver = function( observer ){...};
Subject.prototype.notify = function( context ){...};
```

Then there is extension function that produces mixins:

```
function extend( extension, obj ){
  for ( var key in extension ){
    obj[key] = extension[key];
  }
}
```

And the following code creates concrete subject being a checkbox:

```
var controlCheckbox = document.getElementById( "mainCheckbox" );

// Extend the controlling checkbox with the Subject class
extend( new Subject(), controlCheckbox );
```

My question here is why `controlCheckbox` was mixed-in instead of inheriting from `Subject` class?

Comment: Because they only want to instrument that particular checkbox?

Comment: You can't really change the prototype chain of a DOM element.

Comment: It's not `controlCheckbox` being mixed into `new Subject()` -- it's the other way around.  `controlCheckbox` (crappy name, btw) is gaining the behaviors associated with a `Subject`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question here is why `controlCheckbox` was mixed-in instead of inheriting from `Subject` class?

Because `controlCheckBox` is an instance of [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), which we can't let (and don't want to) inherit from arbitrary classes.

Mixing an interface (`Subject`) into a DOM element or even DOM class [is questionable anyway](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/), it might have been a better idea to create a wrapper object (`new Subject(document.getElementById("mainCheckbox"))`).